# Exported MariaDB dump different size

Tags: mysql, debian, database, mariadb

I'm trying to copy a database from a MariaDB server on another. I made a dump of the database on server A with :

```
sudo mysqldump -u root -p --databases database1 > /var/tmp/database1.sql
```

I created the new database on server B with :

```
create database database1;
```

Then I copied the .sql dump file from server A to server B with scp and imported it on server B with :

```
sudo mysql -u root -p database1 < database1.sql
```

However, the two databases seem to not have the same size :

Server A :

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT table_schema "database1", ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB"  FROM information_schema.tables  GROUP BY table_schema;
+--------------------+---------------+
| database1          | DB Size in MB |
+--------------------+---------------+
| information_schema |           0.2 |
| mysql              |           2.5 |
| performance_schema |           0.0 |
| database1          |         516.7 |
+--------------------+---------------+
```

Server B :

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT table_schema "database1",ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB"  FROM information_schema.tables  GROUP BY table_schema;
+--------------------+---------------+
| database1          | DB Size in MB |
+--------------------+---------------+
| information_schema |           0.2 |
| mysql              |           0.7 |
| performance_schema |           0.0 |
| database1          |         456.8 |
+--------------------+---------------+
```

Also, If I look at the same table on both database, they seem to not have the same number of lines. I've tried to copy the database multiple times but always get a difference. Is there something I'm missing ? I'm not an expert on MariaDB. Both server are under Debian 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is normal.  Here is what happened:

- `mysqldump` generates `INSERT` statements from the BTree-structured data.
- The reload executes those statements, filling up a BTree with the data.
- BTrees are designed for flexibility -- you can add a record in the middle of a table;
- A BTree is composed of "blocks" (16KB each in the case of InnoDB)
- If an insert goes into a 'full' block, then that block is 'split' -- 16KB suddenly became 32KB.  A lot of this can cause a table to grow.
- On the other hand, the dump was *probably* done in "order".  In that case the reload *might* pack the blocks better than would happen from random inserts/deletes.
- This reload is *likely* to be smaller, but not necessarily.

Meanwhile...

`SHOW TABLE STATUS` gives only an *estimate* of the number of rows.  If you want the exact number of rows, use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename`.  (one table at a time)  Since the `STATUS` is an "estimate", it may be more or less than the real count; sometimes by a significant amount.  Again this is "normal".